# Validate existing values in the Postgres table before inserting the row

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA and Hibernate to connect  to a table and insert data in the same. I have a table say : User which has three columns ID, Name and Address. I have an entity class for the same and to insert the data I simply use the EntityManager's object and persist the data in the db which works like a charm for me.

Now I have a scenario where I want to check whether the values that I am persisting already exist, if that is the case I have to log an error. Currently how I am doing that is manually loading the rows from the table and manually checking if the same values exist or not which is fairly simple for the example table (User) that has only  three columns. But what if I have a table with 30 columns?

Do I manually  load the data based on one condition and check for other columns or is there a better and a short way to do that ?

Comment: Use a table constraint to disallow duplicate rows.

Comment: +1 to @Kayaman, Use Db constraint.
else sql/hql query is the only option.

Comment: Find your tables' unique subset of columns and apply a constraint for each. -- To stay at your example, let's say we have a `users` table with a bunch of columns. It is highly unlikely that you want to allow 2 separate rows in which the `email` column is the same, but let's say the `favourite_color` is different.

Answer (score 0):

30 columns, is that you primary key as? If the data you are checking for duplication is the primary key, or unique constraint then you can use Hibnerate to fetch an object before save and report back if it exists. If the 30 columns are not part of the key then I would use equals method, and as such fetch all rows. However if there are many rows and this would be slow then I would probably write an dedicated SQL to check wherever an object exists, i.e.

`UserDao public boolean rowExists(User user) { ... }`

Comment: Unfortunately the 30 columns we need to check are not a part  of the key, that makes it tricky. With your solution the problem is we don't have to check all 30 columns but maybe 25  columns

Comment: This is a very poor general solution. If there are no table constraints, any simple multithreaded code will be able to insert duplicates unless you're heavily using serialized transactions.

Comment: @AnkushBhan: you can always create a unique index on those columns - but having 30 columns that should be unique sounds like a strange requirement to me.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, the requirement is not to have all 30 columns  with unique values. If any one column is different we still will persist the data, but yes if for all the columns the values are same then we log an error.

Comment: @AnkushBhan: I understand that, and you _can_ do that with a unique index. But it still sounds like a strange requirement. It might be better if you edited your question and add the table definition and some sample data to show what exactly you are trying to do. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Are your tables normalized? That is all columns depend upon primary key?

Comment: @ToreSk Yes I have a unique self generated id for my table that works as a primary key. I don't manually insert that. And it is not that normalized, its just one table with 30 columns with one id per row as a primary key

Comment: Well if you do not normalize your tables then you will most likely run into these issues with lots of checks on data.